# Testing cell protection for condtional formatting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel 2010, I want to use conditional formatting (to color the cell) if the cell is protected. Can you suggest the appropriate formula? I think it is IF(CELL("PROTECT").... something, but what?

Answer (score 1):

You need a two step process

1. Identify that the cell is locked (which is what `=CELL("protect",A1)` does
2. Check that the sheet is protected (as locked cells are are protected when the sheet is password protected)

Happily there is a workaround to uses VBA for (2), we can use the XLM/Range Name approach to identify if the sheet is protected (see [my article here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_7629-Using-XLM-with-Range-Names-and-Conditional-Formatting-to-automatically-format-spreadsheets-according-to-cell-content.html)) for further info on this method

To set-up for part 2

- Goto **Formula**
- Insert a new name `=IsShtProtect1` referring to `=GET.DOCUMENT(7)+RAND()*0 (see bottom diagram)

This range name will return 1 if the sheet is protected, 0 if it is unprotected.

You can now apply the conditional formatting

1. Select your range of interest, *staring from the top left corner*
2. Use a formula to select which cells to format
3. add this rule `=AND(IsShtProtect=1,CELL("protect",A1)=1)`

This rule is TRUE when the cell is both locked and protected (A16:I20 in the example below)
[image]

[image]